# BooleanFieldEditor doesn't load value from PreferenceStore

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

For an own PreferencePage in an Eclipse-RCP-Plugin I use an BooleanFieldEditor. Its value is saved in the PreferenceStore (confirmed that it is saved).
But the Editor always is set to "false" after opening the PreferencePage again.

```
public class PreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements
IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

[...]
protected void createFieldEditors() {
subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor = new BooleanFieldEditor
    (PreferenceConstants.FIELD_SUBVERSION_SUPPORT, "Enable Subversion support", BooleanFieldEditor.DEFAULT, getFieldEditorParent());
subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor.setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
subversionSupportBooleanFieldEditor.load();
[...]}
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `doGetPreferenceStore` method of `PreferencePage` and return the preference store that should be used by the field editors.

```
  @Override
  protected IPreferenceStore doGetPreferenceStore() {
    return Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
  }
```

The `initialize` method of `FieldEditorPreferencePage` assigns the value returned here to each field editor. If you do not override `doGetPreferenceStore` the preference store of the `container` is taken.